# How to test if a remote server is down for maintenance even though there may be a redirect to a maintenance page?

Tags: php, webserver

We have an application that is dependent upon a remote service. I have been asked to implement some code whereby if the remote web server is down (due to maintenance or glithes) that I display an appropriate message.

The issue at hand is that when the remote is down for maintenance, they usually redirect to another page. So how do I get about implementing in PHP a robust function that can tell if a particular URL is up and running as opposed to it being redirected to a dummy page.

Thank You

Comment: do they send different headers in the response? If not, the only way it to check the body of the response.

Comment: redirection is http 30something, OK is 200..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: check if a site is down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144825/php-check-if-a-site-is-down)

Answer (score 1):

Just **check the response text**. If the the response contains any text that is present in the redirected url, Then its surely in maintenance mode.

If the remote web server is down you can check it too. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144825/php-check-if-a-site-is-down/9145124#9145124

Answer (score 1):

Just check the HTTP return code. This is possible with curl for instance:

CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

```
<?php
$success = 0;
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occured
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
 if(curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200)
    $success = 1;
}

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```