# Loop domains and check if they're down

Tags: php, loops, file-get-contents

I'm looping an array of domains and checking if they're down/offline. Currently, I'm doing this with a `foreach` loop and `file_get_contents()`. This seems to work, but I think it's a bit slow and I'm not sure if what I'm doing is a suitable approach, that there isn't a better way to handle this.

Example test:

```
<?php

$domains = [
    "stackoverflow.com", // 49 KB
    "google.com",        // 68 KB
    "facebook.com",      // 112 KB
    "zyxwv.com",         // 0
    "youtube.com",       // 38 KB
    "imdb.com",          // 56 KB
    "zyxwv1234.com",     // 0
    "mozilla.org",       // 152 KB
    "amazon.com",        // 100 KB
    "github.com",        // 80 KB  >  total = 655 KB
];

ini_set("max_execution_time", count($domains) * 10); // 10 seconds for each domain

$states = [];

foreach ($domains as $domain) {

    $sw_dom_start   = microtime(1);
    $sw_dom_elapsed = null;

    try {

        $contents = @file_get_contents("http://{$domain}");

        $sw_dom_stop = microtime(1);
        $sw_dom_elapsed = $sw_dom_stop - $sw_dom_start;

        if ($contents) {
            $states[] = [$domain, "online", $sw_dom_elapsed];
        } else {
            $states[] = [$domain, "offline", $sw_dom_elapsed];
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $states[] = [$domain, "offline", $sw_dom_elapsed];
    }
}

$durations = array_reduce($states, function ($sum, $state) { $sum += $state[2]; return $sum; });
var_dump($durations);

/*
recorded durations : 22.7, 37.5, 43.6, 34.8, 20.4

example output:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stackoverflow.com
            [1] => online
            [2] => 0.90218901634216
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => google.com
            [1] => online
            [2] => 0.51400780677795
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => facebook.com
            [1] => online
            [2] => 1.2972490787506
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => zyxwv.com
            [1] => offline
            [2] => 11.007841110229
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => youtube.com
            [1] => online
            [2] => 2.3354029655457
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => imdb.com
            [1] => online
            [2] => 1.1368417739868
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => zyxwv1234.com
            [1] => offline
            [2] => 0.10531902313232
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => mozilla.org
            [1] => online
            [2] => 8.8756558895111
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => amazon.com
            [1] => online
            [2] => 2.3273060321808
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => github.com
            [1] => online
            [2] => 1.3067789077759
        )

)
float(29.808591604233) */
```

Sometimes I get inconsistent results. Offline/made-up domains take up to 10 seconds to process, and online sites can reach 8 seconds. I'm not sure if this is about my code or the target domains.

I've noted the size of the index pages and they do not weight much. 10 pages amount to 655 KB. This should be retrieved like in a few seconds. So if the size is not affecting the performance, what does? Is `file_get_contents()` an expensive call?

I'll be checking 150+ domains regularly (a few times in a day, maybe). The current approach seems like a bad one for this task. A complete loop would take around 10 minutes, and that's if it doesn't fail. How should I proceed?

Comment: Yes, `file_get_contents` is expensive, especially for larger chunks of data. Why not just retrieve the headers using `get_headers()` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test if a remote server is down for maintenance even though there may be a redirect to a maintenance page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808405/how-to-test-if-a-remote-server-is-down-for-maintenance-even-though-there-may-be)

Comment: You should use cURL and get that on a cron and save results to database. You can then put a bigger timeout and get accurate results. You can also save the last crawl time and show that in your page. If you crawl every hours or so you can get pretty accurate results.

Comment: @BenM Switched to `get_headers()`, but it still takes long. Especially on the first "down" domain (zyxwv.com), like 11 seconds. On the second "down" domain, it checks instantly. Weird. On a test I just did, it took 7 seconds for "facebook.com". So headers didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
foreach ($domains as $domain) {

http_response($domain,'200',3); // returns true if the response takes less than 3 seconds and the response code is 200
}

function http_response($url, $status = null, $wait = 3)
{
    $time = microtime(true);
    $expire = $time + $wait;

    // we fork the process so we don't have to wait for a timeout
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid == -1) {
        die('could not fork');
    } else if ($pid) {
        // we are the parent
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $head = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        if(!$head)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if($status === null)
        {
            if($httpCode < 400)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        elseif($status == $httpCode)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
        pcntl_wait($status); //Protect against Zombie children
    } else {
        // we are the child
        while(microtime(true) < $expire)
        {
        sleep(0.5);
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: This (the way it is) didn't help me because PCNTL function doesn't exists for me. I just decided to use `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents()` and `get_headers()` didn't really solve my problem. I think that's because there's no timeout for the connections, so it just waits and waits for each domain.

I've looked into cURL and got it working. I believe this is my first use of cURL.

I set up a 3 seconds timeout for the connections. If a domain doesn't repond in 3 seconds, it's offline. While this might be true for actually offline/down domains, sometimes even online domains fail to respond in 3 seconds. Since I can't detect if it's really down or it's waiting for a response at the moment of the connection, I have to do a second check.

I do a second check on "offline" domains just to make sure they're really offline, and this setup seems to work. The only difference in the second change is the timeout and this time it's 5 seconds. Checking 10 domains takes about 10 seconds. Sometimes even much shorter.

Example test:

```
<?php

$sw_start = microtime(1);

$domains = [
    "stackoverflow.com",
    "google.com",
    "facebook.com",
    "zyxwv.com",
    "youtube.com",
    "imdb.com",
    "zyxwv1234.com",
    "mozilla.org",
    "amazon.com",
    "github.com",
];

ini_set("max_execution_time", count($domains) * 10);

function curl_is_online($url, $timeout = 3) {

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);

    $head = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($head) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

function check_domain($domain) {
    $sw_start   = microtime(1);
    $sw_elapsed = null;

    $result = [
        "domain"  => $domain,
        "state"   => "offline",
        "latency" => $sw_elapsed,
    ];

    try {

        $is_online = curl_is_online("http://{$domain}");

        $sw_stop = microtime(1);
        $sw_elapsed = $sw_stop - $sw_start;

        if ($is_online) {
            $result["state"] = "online";
        }
        $result["latency"] = $sw_elapsed;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result["state"]   = "offline";
        $result["latency"] = $sw_elapsed;
    }

    return $result;
}

function check_domains($domains) {
    $checks = [];
    foreach ($domains as $domain) {
        $checks[] = check_domain($domain);
    }
    return $checks;
}

function check_offlines(&$checks, $timeout = 5) {
    foreach ($checks as &$check) {
        if ($check["state"] == "offline") {
            print_r($check);
            $check = check_domain($check["domain"], $timeout);
        }
    }
}

$checks = check_domains($domains);
print_r($checks);

check_offlines($checks);
print_r($checks);

$sw_stop = microtime(1);
$sw_elapsed = $sw_stop - $sw_start;
echo "Total elapsed time: {$sw_elapsed} seconds.";
```